# If I have two connections to the internet how do I choose which applications use which

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I know that I can bridge two networks in Windows. But I have a problem with that. One of my connections is a mobile broadband that has no data limit but has relatively slow speeds. The other is a wifi network with very high speeds but with a monthly limit of 15 gigabytes. I want my regular browser traffic to use my mobile broadband and my torrent client and download manager to use my wifi network. Is this possible with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Some bittorrent clients and download managers allow you to select which network interface to use. For example in qBittorrent you can select it under Options/Advanced/Network Interface. In JDownloader you can find the setting in the connection manager.
https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=66979